# Karate : How to use response of scenario in afterScenario

Tags: configure, karate, scenarios

What is the best way to use the response of scenario in afterScenario??

```
Background:    
   * configure afterScenario = function(response){if(response.key){ karate.log('key is present');} else{karate.log('key is not present');} }

    Scenario: get all users 

    Given path 'users'
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try function without input params

```
* configure afterScenario = function(){if(response.key){ karate.log('key is present');} else{karate.log('key is not present');} }
```

if the `response` variable available for hooks this should work.