# How to fetch correlation id from the karate dsl api response?

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

I am new to karate dsl. I want to fetch the correlation id (when there is a failure) from the response details. how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 questions here. To do something on a failure, see `afterScenario`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55113387/143475

By co-relation id, I am assuming you mean you want to get a header out of the response.  Refer to the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#responseheaders

If you are new to karate dsl - I recommend you get some basic tests working first. In my opinion, the above 2 are advanced topics.